# Borrar todas las tablas excepto algunas mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una bbdd `mysql` con 65 tablas y necesito  crear un script que la limpie para una futura subida a producción.

Como tengo que borrar la mayoria de tablas, excepto las de datos internos (tipos de usuarios, secciones, permisos, categorias predeterminadas etc...) he pensado en borrarlas todas excepto las que necesito conservar.

**¿Hay alguna manera, en `mysql`, de borrar los datos de todas las tablas (truncate) excepto las que esten en una lista?**

Aunque sea más trabajo, también me serviría la opción contraria: hacer el borrado de datos de todas las tablas que estén en una lista.

Comment: Por que se pide el cierre de esta pregunta? Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel la verdad es que no lo sé, he pensado en editarla, pero creo que, pese a no incluir código, la pregunta es suficientemente clara... :$ Aunque estoy abierto a sugerencias para mejorarla. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una posible solución con dos variantes:

1. Crea una tabla que contendrá nombres de tablas.
2. Crea un procedimiento almacenado que:

   - Variante A:

     1. Selecciona todas las tablas cuyo nombre está en la tabla creada.
     2. Hace un truncate de esas tablas.
   - Variante B:

     1. Selecciona todas las tablas cuyo nombre **no** está en la tabla creada.
     2. Hace un truncate de esas tablas.
3. Llama al procedimiento almacenado cada vez que quieras borrar las tablas.

Las variantes son ejemplos de listas blancas o listas negras: la variante A contiene una lista negra que indica qué tablas se deben borrar (el resto se dejarán tal cual), mientras que la variante B contiene una lista blanca con las tablas que deben mantenerse (y las demás se truncarán).

Dependiendo del número de tablas a borrar o de cada cuándo se actualice la lista de tablas a borrar podrías decidirte por una o por otra. Si sabes que las tablas que no se deben borrar van a ser constantes pero que las que se van a borrar puede variar, optaría por la opción B.

Aquí dejo un ejemplo de cómo podría hacerse:

> En este ejemplo:
>
> - stackoverflow es el nombre de la base de datos donde se encuentran las tablas a truncar.
> - tablas_a_borrar es la tabla que contiene los nombres de las tablas a truncar.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS truncar_tablas $$
CREATE PROCEDURE truncar_tablas()
BEGIN

    DECLARE x INT;
    DECLARE numtablas INT;
    DECLARE nombretabla VARCHAR(100);

    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

    SELECT COUNT(nombre) INTO numtablas FROM tablas_a_borrar;
    SET x = 0;

    -- hacemos un bucle que leerá todos los nombres de las tablas
    truncate_loop: LOOP

        -- si ya hemos atravesado todas las tablas, salimos del bucle
        IF x > numtablas THEN
            LEAVE truncate_loop;
        END IF;

        -- seleccionamos el nombre de la tabla
        SELECT nombre
        INTO   nombretabla
        FROM   tablas_a_borrar
        LIMIT  x, 1;

        -- construímos dinámicamente el TRUNCATE para la siguiente tabla
        SELECT CONCAT('TRUNCATE ',GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('stackoverflow.',table_name)),';')
        INTO @codigotruncar 
        FROM information_schema.tables 
        WHERE 'stackoverflow' = database()
          AND table_name IN (SELECT DISTINCT nombre FROM tablas_a_borrar WHERE nombre = nombretabla); 

        -- preparamos y ejecutamos el SQL dinamicamente
        PREPARE stmt FROM @codigotruncar;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

        SET x = x + 1;

    END LOOP;

    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Después ya sólo tendrías que llamar al procedimiento almacenado de este modo: `call truncar_tablas;` para truncar todas las tablas especificadas en la tabla `tablas_a_borrar`.

Comment: Adicional a esto, recomendaria utilizar la sentencia `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0` al comienzo del script y `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1` al final o en caso de error, para evitar problemas al truncar una tabla con llave foránea. Asimismo, tener en cuenta que en MySQL no existe rollback para la sentencia `TRUNCATE`.

Comment: entiendo el sistema que propones, pero como paso el parámetro al truncate de la stored procedure? @rnrneverdies comenta en su respuesta que no se puede hacer  `TRUNCATE @tablename`

Comment: @JordiCastilla si puedes hacer `TRUNCATE @tablename`. Lo que debes hacer es ejecutar script de forma dinámica. Mira la información de este link (en inglés): http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/06/20/mysql-dynamic-sql-with-execute-and-prepare-statements/ Dado que no tengo mucho tiempo no puedo preparar un ejemplo (y una respuesta) para tu caso

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Gracias por la recomendación, lo añadí en el ejemplo.

Comment: @JordiCastilla he añadido un ejemplo de cómo se podría crear el procedimiento almacenado

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza eso no es hacer `TRUNCATE TABLE @tablename`, es crear la sentencia dinamincamente, no se puede poner una parametro (que empieza con @) en las partes estructurales de la consulta, tabla o nombre de columna. En el ejemplo @tablename es un parametro pasado al metodo CONTAC, muy parecido a lo que puse en mi respuesta,

Comment: @rnrneverdies es cuestión de interpretación, y diría que técnicamente no se puede hacer, pero puedes obtener el texto `TRUNCATE @tablename` desde una tabla donde esten guardadas los nombres de las tablas que vas a truncar p.e. `SELECT CONCAT('TRUNCATE ', tableName) FROM tablas /* quizas un WHERE aca */` y luego ejecutar esas sentencias de manera dinámica (como lo indico en mi comentario). Que yo sepa, no puedes utilizar el nombre de una tabla como parámetro para ninguna operación DML a menos que ejecutes el query dinámicamente (donde sí puedes colocar parámetros de acuerdo a tus necesidades).

Comment: gracias Alvaro y @LuiggiMendoza ,mañana tendré tiempo para probar esto, os respondo con cualquier problema :) :)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro funciona como diría Jesulín de Ubrique en tres palabras: **PER-FEC-TO**. He tenido una NULL exception, pero ha sido por mi culpa ya que tenia una typo en una de las tablas. Pero siguiendo las truncadas y las que no lo he encontrado rapido. MIL GRACIAS!

Answer (score 3):

### Actualización:

La misma solución implementada dentro de un store procedure con SQL utilizando [EXECUTE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) dentro de un loop sobre un cursor con las tablas a truncar.

Este store procedure espera una tabla llamada `excepciones` con la lista de tablas que no se deben truncar en un campo llamado `nombre_tabla`, la lista de tablas la toma de la tabla de sistema `information_schema.tables`

Sería mas o menos así:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE truncateAlgunas() BEGIN
  DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE nombreTabla VARCHAR(64);
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
              SELECT table_name 
              FROM information_schema.tables 
              WHERE table_name NOT IN (SELECT nombreTabla FROM excepciones);
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;

  OPEN cur;

  truncateLoop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO nombreTabla;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE truncateLoop;
    END IF;
    PREPARE statement FROM CONCAT("TRUNCATE TABLE ", nombreTabla);
    EXECUTE statement;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
  END LOOP truncateLoop;

  CLOSE cur;
END
```

Y luego lo simplemente ejecutas el store procedure. Esto es lo mismo que dije antes pero implementado en mysql.

Nota: no pude probarlo, pero debería funcionar sin cambios mayores.

#### Respuesta anterior

Hasta donde se no puedes usar parámetros para el nombres de las tablas (o columnas) (ej:`TRUNCATE TABLE @tablename`), así que se enfoque lo descarto.

Una solución posible sería, utilizando cualquier otro lenguaje, y a mano concatenar el nombre de la tabla a la sentencia `truncate table`.

```
List<String> tablas = { "a", "b", "c" };
List<String> excepciones = { "b" };
String sentencia;

for(var tabla in tablas) {
    if (!excepciones.contains(tabla)) {
        sentencia += "TRUNCATE TABLE " + tabla + ";"; 
    }
}

mySqlConnection.execute(sentencia);
```

Esto podrias hacerlo tambien utilizando SQL. Igualmente, dependiendo del origen (la confiabilidad) de la lista de tablas y excepciones, deberías revisar el valor de `tabla` por caracteres de control para evitar [sql injection](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Mas info en [este post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2754443/2573335) de SO en inglés

Answer (score 0):

La forma mas sencilla y como yo lo hago es atraves de los ID, me solucinan la vida cuando existen valores numéricos, solo hago:

```
DELETE FROM "tabla" where "codigoid" < "135"
```

En este ejemplo mi es la tabla y la columna es codigoid y estoy pidiéndole que me elimine todos los valores menores a 135, quizá puedas probar algo parecido para comenzar