# Borrar registros con loop mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una base de datos con 8 tablas y tengo que borrar todos los registros de esas tablas con una sola instrucción pero sin afectar la estructura de las tablas de la base de datos, he escuchado que con un loop es posible pero la verdad no me queda claro, alguien podría ayudarme?

Comment: Puedes mostrar que has investigado y en base a las dudas que te surjan te podemos ayudar.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3098/96571 esta pregunta es parecida, pero yo quiero eliminar todos los registros de todas mis tablas usando un loop como ese, pero no se bien como funciona, soy nuevo con mysql.

Comment: Si quieres borrar todos los registros de tus tablas de una forma más rápida puedes hacerlo por medio de TRUNCATE, busca algo de información. TRUNCATE TABLE , asi lo vas a encontrar.